# Mounting and Unmounting of Memory Card just by touch?

Tags: security, external-sd, mount

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Y mobile phone. In my mobile's settings, I see an option to "Unmount the Memory Card for Safe Removal", so it is possible to unmount the memory card without actually removing the card or connecting the mobile with a computer.

I was wondering whether it is possible to Mount the Memory Card back again without actually removing the unmounted card and inserting it again?

A situation in which it may be useful:

I have an Android phone and there is a lot of personal stuff that I cannot let anyone see. I store all the apps containing the personal data in my memory card. Many of my friends and/or Girlfriend ask me my mobile to "check it out"/"play games" etc... At that point of time, I unmount my memory card with just a touch, give it to them and when I get it back I mount the memory card again with just a touch. I do it right in front of them and they have no idea.

Comment: I have a Samsung I9305 running 4.4.4 and on my phone there's a "mount SD card" button that appears in the very same place that the "unmount" button was prior to unmounting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: I am on Samsung Galaxy S2, Android 4.0.3

[Elixir for Android](http://bartat.hu/) has an "sd mount toggle" feature. It could unmount a removable card (/mnt/sdcard/external_sd), but not (/mnt/sdcard). I could not get it to mount by clicking the toggle again, but a restart [toggle also available] will mount the removable card. This is probably a bug with Elixir; and I will try to contact the developer.

Comment: It looks like I made a mistake. I should have mounted /mnt/emmc, not /mnt/sdcard/external_sd. The toggle works (mount, unmount).

Comment: Is this working on Android 4.4 or above?